# different size of c data type in 32 and 64 bit

Tags: c, architecture

Why there is different size of C data types in 32bit and 64 bit system...

for example: int size in 32bit is 4 byte and 8 byte in 64bit

what is the reason behind it to double the size of data types in 64bit as well as My knowledge is concern there is no performance issue if we are going to use same size in 64 bit system as it is in 32 bit....

Comment: Because standard allows it to be. The reason is mainly historical and backward compatibility. If you need fixed width integers, look at `<stdint.h>` provided by C99.

Comment: 64 bit processors have registers that work with 64 bit numbers. On 32 bit processors, these operations on 64 bit numbers are "emulated" thus being slower.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing ,  IL32P64 and  I32LP64 are the majority, so "int size in 32bit is 4 byte and 8 byte in 64bit" is very inaccurate.

Comment: Also 64 bit data types can have performance impacts, depending on on implementation. For this reason x32 ABI has been invented to downgrade the pointer size back to 32 bit on x86-64 hardware and has shown better performance over x86-64. Similarly Android on ARM64 also choose to use a 32 bit user space. For the same reason, int type stayed at 16 bit for a long time after i386 was released.

Comment: You forgot to tell why you expect them to have the same size. And why don't you ask only ask about 32 and 64, not 8 or 16 bit systems? Or 18 or 24 bit systems?

Comment: On most 32-bit and 64-bit systems, `sizeof(int) == 4` (assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8) — though the standards allow it to be as small as 2 (16-bit `int` is valid) or larger.  The size of `long` can be different; on 32-bit systems, it is normally the same size as `int`, but on Unix-based 64-bit systems, it is usually 8 (64 bits) whereas on 64-bit Windows it is still 4 (32 bits).  Have fun.  Try Java if you want the same sizes everywhere.  C is older and differently regulated from Java.

Comment: Olaf...  because I think there is same reason behind it and currently 32 bit and 64 bit running thats why I am asking that.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why there is different size of C data types in 32bit and 64 bit system[?]

The sizes of C's basic data types are implementation-dependent.  They are not necessarily dependent on machine architecture, and counterexamples abound.  For example, 32-bit and 64-bit implementations of GCC use the same size data types for x86 and x86_64.

> what is the reason behind it to double the size of data types in 64bit[?]

The reasons for implementation decisions vary with implementors and implementation characteristics.  `int` is often, but not always, chosen to have a size that is natural for the target machine in some sense.  That might mean that operations on it are fast, or that it is efficient to load from and store to memory, or other things.  These are the kinds of considerations involved.

Answer (score 0):

The C language definition does not mandate a specific size for most data types; instead, specifies the *range* of values each type must be able to represent.  `char` must be large enough to represent a single character of the execution character set (*at least* the range `[-127,127]`), `short` and `int` must be large enough to represent *at least* the range `[-32767,32767]`, etc.

Traditionally, the size of `int` was the same as the "natural" word size for a given architecture, on the premise that a) it would be easier to implement, and b) operations on that type would be the most efficient.  Whether that's still true today, I'm not qualified to say (not a hardware guy).